# How does WF hosted as WCF in IIS 6 resume after delay?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-6, workflow-foundation

Does a WF hosted as WCF (.NET 3.5) in IIS 6 resume after a delay activity when persisted to SqlWorkflowPersistenceService ? And if so, which kind of thread is being used (one from the ASP.NET worker threads or a background thread from IIS ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET code never uses "a thread from IIS 6". It's always an ASP.NET worker thread.

In IIS 7 the two are the same.